# Как сделать загрузку прелоадера только при первом посещении сайта? Не через куки

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

сам код js

```js
(function($){
 
var bdy = jQuery("body");
var value = wsp_obj.loader,  
duration = ( wsp_obj.hasOwnProperty('fadeout') && wsp_obj.fadeout!="" )?wsp_obj.fadeout:2500,
delay = ( wsp_obj.hasOwnProperty('delay') && wsp_obj.delay!="" )?wsp_obj.delay:1500;

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var flag;
  if( wsp_obj.hasOwnProperty("homepage") && ( "1" == wsp_obj.homepage ) ){
   if( jQuery('body').hasClass('home') ){
    add_block_after_body();
    flag = "home";
   }
  } else {
    add_block_after_body();
  } 
  
 setTimeout(wsp_front_loader(),1000);

 function wsp_front_loader() {
  
  
  var block = '';
  if( value != "" ){
   switch (value){
    case "Loader 1":
     block += '<div class="wp-smart-loader smart-loader-one">Loading...</div>';
     break;
    case "Loader 2":
     block += '<div class="wp-smart-loader smart-loader-two"> <span></span> <span></span> <span></span> <span></span> </div>';
     break;
    case "Loader 3":
     block += ' <div class="wp-smart-loader smart-loader-three"> <span></span> <span></span> <span></span> <span></span> <span></span> </div>';
     break;
    case "Loader 4":
     block += ' <div class="wp-smart-loader smart-loader-four"> <span class="spinner-cube spinner-cube1"></span> <span class="spinner-cube spinner-cube2"></span> <span class="spinner-cube spinner-cube3"></span> <span class="spinner-cube spinner-cube4"></span> <span class="spinner-cube spinner-cube5"></span> <span class="spinner-cube spinner-cube6"></span> <span class="spinner-cube spinner-cube7"></span> <span class="spinner-cube spinner-cube8"></span> <span class="spinner-cube spinner-cube9"></span> </div>';
     break;
    case "Loader 5":
     block += ' <div class="wp-smart-loader smart-loader-five"> <span class="spinner-cube-1 spinner-cube"></span> <span class="spinner-cube-2 spinner-cube"></span> <span class="spinner-cube-4 spinner-cube"></span> <span class="spinner-cube-3 spinner-cube"></span> </div>';
     break;
    case "Loader 6":
     block += ' <div class="wp-smart-loader smart-loader-six"> <span class=" spinner-cube-1 spinner-cube"></span> <span class=" spinner-cube-2 spinner-cube"></span> </div>';
     break;
    case "Custom Animation":
     block += wsp_obj.custom_animation;
     break;
   }
   
  
    
   if( "home" == flag ){
    jQuery('body.home .smart-page-loader').prepend(block);
   }else {
    // all pages
    jQuery('.smart-page-loader').prepend(block);
   } 

  }

 }

 function add_block_after_body(){
  jQuery('body').prepend('<div class="smart-page-loader"></div>');
  jQuery('body').removeClass('wp-smart-body');  
 }

 
});

jQuery(window).load(function(){
 
 fade_away();
 
 function fade_away(){
  jQuery('.smart-page-loader').delay(delay).fadeOut(duration);
  jQuery('body').removeClass('wp-smart-body');
 }
 
});

 
}(jQuery));
```

Но он запускает прелоадер каждый раз, как захожу на главную, а надо, чтобы при первом посещении сайта открывалось - и всё. Пытаюсь сделать через localstorage, но не получается. Как правильно сделать?

Пытаюсь так, но вообще не работает

```
    (function($){
      $(window).load(function() {
    if (!window.localStorage.getItem('preloaderIsShown')) {
var bdy = jQuery("body");
var value = wsp_obj.loader,     
duration = ( wsp_obj.hasOwnProperty('fadeout') && wsp_obj.fadeout!="" )?wsp_obj.fadeout:2500,
delay = ( wsp_obj.hasOwnProperty('delay') && wsp_obj.delay!="" )?wsp_obj.delay:1500;

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var flag;
        if( wsp_obj.hasOwnProperty("homepage") && ( "1" == wsp_obj.homepage ) ){
            if( jQuery('body').hasClass('home') ){
                add_block_after_body();
                flag = "home";
            }
        } else {
                add_block_after_body();
        }   

    setTimeout(wsp_front_loader(),1000);

    function wsp_front_loader() {


        var block = '';
        if( value != "" ){
            switch (value){
                case "Loader 1":
                    block += '<div class="wp-smart-loader smart-loader-one">Loading...</div>';
                    break;
                case "Loader 2":
                    block += '<div class="wp-smart-loader smart-loader-two"> <span></span> <span></span> <span></span> <span></span> </div>';
                    break;
                case "Loader 3":
                    block += ' <div class="wp-smart-loader smart-loader-three"> <span></span> <span></span> <span></span> <span></span> <span></span> </div>';
                    break;
                case "Loader 4":
                    block += ' <div class="wp-smart-loader smart-loader-four"> <span class="spinner-cube spinner-cube1"></span> <span class="spinner-cube spinner-cube2"></span> <span class="spinner-cube spinner-cube3"></span> <span class="spinner-cube spinner-cube4"></span> <span class="spinner-cube spinner-cube5"></span> <span class="spinner-cube spinner-cube6"></span> <span class="spinner-cube spinner-cube7"></span> <span class="spinner-cube spinner-cube8"></span> <span class="spinner-cube spinner-cube9"></span> </div>';
                    break;
                case "Loader 5":
                    block += ' <div class="wp-smart-loader smart-loader-five"> <span class="spinner-cube-1 spinner-cube"></span> <span class="spinner-cube-2 spinner-cube"></span> <span class="spinner-cube-4 spinner-cube"></span> <span class="spinner-cube-3 spinner-cube"></span> </div>';
                    break;
                case "Loader 6":
                    block += ' <div class="wp-smart-loader smart-loader-six"> <span class=" spinner-cube-1 spinner-cube"></span> <span class=" spinner-cube-2 spinner-cube"></span> </div>';
                    break;
                case "Custom Animation":
                    block += wsp_obj.custom_animation;
                    break;
            }



            if( "home" == flag ){
                jQuery('body.home .smart-page-loader').prepend(block);
            }else {
                // all pages
                jQuery('.smart-page-loader').prepend(block);
            }   

        }

    }

    function add_block_after_body(){
        jQuery('body').prepend('<div class="smart-page-loader"></div>');
        jQuery('body').removeClass('wp-smart-body');        
    }


});

jQuery(window).load(function(){

    fade_away();

    function fade_away(){
        jQuery('.smart-page-loader').delay(delay).fadeOut(duration);
        jQuery('body').removeClass('wp-smart-body');
    }

});
    } else {
            $('.smart-page-loader').css('display', 'none');
    }

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Какая разница - делать этот функционал через куки или localstorage? Чем куки не угодили?

Comment: @KAGGDesign ну пишут что если через куки, то и через неделю не будет показывать прелоадер)

Comment: А через две? ))) А чем localstorage лучше? Вам же так и надо - один раз показал, и все, отключил навсегда для данного пользователя. Ну и сделайте куки с огромным временем жизни. Если вас заботит, что куки могут удалить, так и localstorage могут почистить))

Comment: @KAGGDesign мне надо чтобы бы при первом входе не показывалось и по истечению некоторого времени снова начинали появлятся, например человек зашел на сайт через часов 12, а у него прелоадер по нвой пошел

Comment: Ну так и делают - через куки со временем жизни в 12 часов.

Comment: @KAGGDesign Ну хорошо, тогда как это сделать?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86537/discussion-between-kagg-design-and-reddyk).

Answer (score 0):

Для установки куки на заданный период времени проще всего использовать плагин [jQuery cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie).

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
    var cookie = $.cookie( 'preloader' );
    if ( typeof cookie === 'undefined' ) {
        // No cookie
        showPreloader();
        // Create cookie
        $.cookie( 'preloader', 'any value', { expires: 1, path: '/' } );
    }
} );
```

В примере куки с именем `preloader` устанавливается на 1 день (expired).

Плагин надо скачать по ссылке выше и подключить на сайте:

```
function my_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.cookie', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.cookie.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```

Comment: Кстати jquery cookie больше не поддерживают. Сейчас https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie рекомендуется (тот же разработчик).

Comment: Да, я видел это. Для ответа просто вытащил код из старого проекта. Лучше новую библиотеку использовать.